# Another sum of exponential functions

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Suppose that we have $q$ complex numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_q$  all inside the unit disk, and that $c_1 \ldots, c_q$ are also complex numbers.  I'm interested in the possible types of behaviors for the function given by $$f(x) = c_1 a_1^{x-1} + \cdots + c_q a_q^{x-1},$$ where $x \in [2,\infty)$.  In particular, I'm interested in the behavior at integer values of $x$ in that range, but I think that the continuous version of $f$ might be easier to handle.

This is a follow up to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97132/sum-of-exponential-functions

Example: here is $1-f(x)$ plotted for

$f(x)=            0.949^x 1.07 +  
 (- 0.325 + 0.459i)^x (- 0.0361 + 0.0446i) +
 (- 0.325 - 0.459i)^x (- 0.0361 - 0.0446i
)$

any intuitions?

[image: f(x)]

Comment: Are $c_{1},c_{2}...,c_{q}$ complex valued too?

Comment: yes, thanks! updated accordingly

Comment: Is there a motivation for using $x-1$ in the exponent and starting $x$ at $2$, as opposed to using $x$ in the exponent and starting $x$ at $1$?